# I'm trying to use a Korean font on Matplotlib, but it is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, cjk

The Korean font I am trying to link is not being applied--the graph is blank where Korean hangul would be.

I tried to link directly to a Korean font so as not to have to provide a local path, but it is still not working. It gives me errors saying the current font does not have that unicode character.

Here's the start of my code where I linked the font.

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import lyricsgenius as genius
from matplotlib import font_manager

font_url = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/nanumgothic.css"
font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=font_url)
```

Comment: follow this link : https://albertauyeung.github.io/2020/03/15/matplotlib-cjk-fonts.html/

Comment: No you can't set a URL. I recommend to install the font in your system, and use the ```fontfamily``` argument to specify the installed font, such as ```plt.title('제목', fontfamily = 'NanumGothic')```

Comment: It seems you want to use NanumGothic. Are you on a Linux desktop? Then in most distribution, you can install the ```fonts-nanum``` package.